linux ip route (interface) selection based on ping to destination?
Intro
I live in Thailand. Our connectivity to Europe here is somewhat strange.
Sometimes connections go directly to Europe (ping of 180-250ms), because my ISP has a direct 100G link to a peering exchange in France. But sometimes this same ISP chooses a much longer route through Singapore-Japan-USA (which causes a ping of 300-400ms and an insane packet loss of 30-50%). Destination in both cases is the same, and the switch happens every time a new connection is established. Contacting the ISP NOC yielded no results.
I somewhat solved the problem by having a dedicated Raspberry at my home connect to a VPN server in Europe which is 1 hop away from that peering exchange in France (which has a direct 100G line to my ISP in Thailand).
This results in my ISP automatically using the fastest route to connect to that VPN 100% of the time. I then have the devices on my LAN use that Raspberry as a gateway when I need a guaranteed fast connection to Europe (you can read here if you want to see how I did this)
The problem
Facebook, Youtube, and basically every other local service in Thailand become slow because 100% of my connections are routed through the VPN in Europe.
Question
Let's say my raspberry gateway has 2 interfaces:

eth0 (the direct connection to my ISP).
tun0 (my VPN connection).

When a new connection is being forwarded by the gateway, is there a way to "pause" it for a few seconds and have the raspberry ping the destination through both interfaces? Once the pings are received, a new static route would be created in the ip table which selects the outgoing interface?
So let's say if I'm trying to connect to facebook.com, the gateway would ping it first through the tun0 (the vpn) and see 300ms, and then through the direct ISP connection (eth0), it would see 30ms. As a result, it would create a static route for this destination via eth0.
I understand that this might slow down the initial connection, however I would be guaranteed to have faster speeds in the end.
Possible solution?
Use NFQUEUE and an external L7 script?
Thank you for reading this.

NFQUEUE is the only possibility here. However, there might be race conditions between updating the route and passing NF_ACCEPTverdict.
